# Issue in c# Window service

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, windows-services

In my window service when I run window service from manage ,ScheduledService file does not contain "Get Connection". I think there is problem in GetConnectionOfReportServer, it may it take more time.
When I debug it is working fine.

**Code Example**

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            TraceService("start service");
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = 90000;
            timer.Enabled = true;

        }
 protected override void OnStop()
        {
            TraceService("stopping service");
        }

 private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

           time_elapsed();
            TraceService("Another entry at " + DateTime.Now);

        }
  private void time_elapsed()
        {           
            TraceService("Call susseccfully");
            GetConnectionOfReportServer();//The problem is here.
            TraceService("Get Connection");
            DailyReportFile = getReportFrmServer(reportName, param);
        }
    public void GetConnectionOfReportServer()
        {
           TraceService("I am in GetConnectionOfReportServer "); //**Edit part**

            try
            {
                NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("administrator", "epass@123");
                this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = credential;
                this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
                this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ReportServer");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
 private void TraceService(string content)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\ScheduledService.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            sw.WriteLine(content);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
```

**Edit Method**

```
  public void GetConnectionOfReportServer()
        {
            TraceService("I am in GetConnectionOfReportServer.");
            try
            {
                TraceService("I am in Try.");
                //NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("administrator", "espl@123","");
                NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("administrator", "esmart@123");
                this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = credential;

                //select where the report should be generated with the report viewer control or on the report server using the SSRS service.
                this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
                this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ReportServer");
                TraceService("I am atTry end");




            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TraceService(ex.StackTrace);

            }
            finally
            {
                TraceService("I am in finally block");
            }
        }
```

But when I am seeing my "ScheduledService File"

start service

Call susseccfully

Find punch

Yes have to send

Yes have to send,

I am in GetConnectionOfReportServer.

I am in Try.   // After this line It should be print "I am at Try end"

Call susseccfully.

After it  again call **OnElapsedTime** event.

Comment: your catch block is empty.  Add `ex.Message; ex.stackTrace` to figure the error message and trace teh error prone line.

Comment: Yes, I have the added the TraceService() at the first line in the function...and also added finally block but dont know why the control is not  coming in the function.....

Comment: No.  Add some what like this`catch (Exception ex)
            {
               TraceService(ex.Message(); ex.StackTrace(););
            } `